# Define newcommand to change the color of the href links to black

Tags: hyperref, color, hyperlink

By default, I have used `hyperref` and `xcolor` to set the color of some of the URL links in my resume, but I also want to have some hidden links which are working, but not shown. Like the names of the companies I worked for, should lead to their respective homepages, but I want those links not to be colored in blue.

I was thinking that I can create a new command `bwhref` but I don't know how I can do it. I found an answer here but it is using the `\documentclass{beamer}`  and I have already set my class to. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Colored links by default
\definecolor{marineblue}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.5}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=marineblue,
}

% Here I want to define bwhref, which will revert to black on the URLs.
% \newcommand{\bwhref}{???}

\begin{document}

% {\bwhref{https://company_a.com}{Company A (black link)}}
\href{https://test.com}{blue link}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By hidden, do you must mean `\hypersetup{urlcolor=\normalcolor}` or do you mean `\hypersetup{hidelinks}`?  Keep in mind that these change are local to the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group command `\hypersetup` and `\href` like this:

```
% Here I want to define bwhref, which will revert to black on the URLs.
\newcommand{\bwhref}[2]{
  {\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black,}
  \href{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
```

to get an own command or you can use `\href` and grouped `\hypersetup` as two commands like:

```
{\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black,}
\href{https://company_a.com}{Company A (black link)}}
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Colored links by default
\definecolor{marineblue}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.5}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=red,
}

% Here I want to define bwhref, which will revert to black on the URLs.
\newcommand{\bwhref}[2]{
  {\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black,}
  \href{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

{\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black,}
\href{https://company_a.com}{Company A (black link)}}

\bwhref{https://company_a.com}{Company A (black link, command)}

\href{https://test.com}{blue link}

\end{document}
```

you get the resulting page with wished result:

[image]

For better seeing I changed your blue color to red ...

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a lot @Mensch

Comment: be aware that you can run into problem if the url contains special chars like % or #.

Comment: by the way, for the new `bwhref` command, you can drop the `colorlinks=true`, it should work fine with `urlcolor=black` only.